# How to get spatial reference in ArcGIS Server identify response

Tags: arcgis-server, javascript, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, coordinate-system, identify

I'm using the ArcGIS API for JavaScript to query features in a web map. After sending an identify request to my ArcGIS Server 10.2.2 Map Service (added as `ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer`, the response is missing a spatialReference object, which in my application causes the parsed feature to default to WGS 1984 (EPSG: 4326).

This is my request:

http://my.server.ip:6080/arcgis/rest/services/MyMapService/MapServer/identify?f=json&geometry=%7B%22x%22:1452552.552270479,%22y%22:7513080.65512973,%22spatialReference%22:%7B%22wkid%22:102100%7D%7D&tolerance=5&returnGeometry=true&mapExtent=%7B%22xmin%22:1400269.6249234888,%22ymin%22:7501309.352773828,%22xmax%22:1547028.7192308295,%22ymax%22:7531884.164087858,%22spatialReference%22:%7B%22wkid%22:102100%7D%7D&imageDisplay=400,400,96&geometryType=esriGeometryPoint&sr=102100&layers=all:1

Notably, is specifyes using the Spherical Mercator projection (Google/OSM etc) in these three parameters:

```
sr: 102100,
geometry:{"x":1452552.552270479,"y":7513080.65512973,"spatialReference":{"wkid":102100}}
mapExtent:{"xmin":1400269.6249234888,"ymin":7501309.352773828,"xmax":1547028.7192308295,"ymax":7531884.164087858,"spatialReference":{"wkid":102100}}
```

The response comes back like this (indented for legibility):

```
{
  "results": [{
    "layerId":1,
    "layerName":"MyLayer",
    "displayFieldName":"objectTitle",
    "value":"TestTitle",
    "attributes": {
      "geom":"Polygon",
      "objectTitle":"TestTitle",
      "ESRI_OID":"5"
    },
    "geometryType":"esriGeometryPolygon",
    "geometry": {
      "rings": [
        [
          [1454668.8173357714,7517201.4526984785],
          [1455184.6049274686,7515021.5271282298],
          [1454315.3831670529,7513419.0967461951],
          [1453618.9498499723,7512120.8890253156],
          [1452935.2001523944,7510514.1489123777],
          [1452177.4970599019,7510191.5673684804],
          [1450715.0293152332,7515680.0804733364],
          [1453744.8112331014,7517255.1012338968],
          [1454668.8173357714,7517201.4526984785]
        ]
      ]
    }
  }]
}
```

The same request sent to my ArcGIS Server 10.2.1 server returns the same response but with a spatialReference at the end of the feature:

```
{
  "results": [{
    "layerId":1,
    "layerName":"MyLayer",
    "displayFieldName":"objectTitle",
    "value":"TestTitle",
    "attributes": {
      "geom":"Polygon",
      "objectTitle":"TestTitle",
      "ESRI_OID":"5"
    },
    "geometryType":"esriGeometryPolygon",
    "geometry": {
      "rings": [
        [
          [1454668.8173357714,7517201.4526984785],
          [1455184.6049274686,7515021.5271282298],
          [1454315.3831670529,7513419.0967461951],
          [1453618.9498499723,7512120.8890253156],
          [1452935.2001523944,7510514.1489123777],
          [1452177.4970599019,7510191.5673684804],
          [1450715.0293152332,7515680.0804733364],
          [1453744.8112331014,7517255.1012338968],
          [1454668.8173357714,7517201.4526984785]
        ]
      ],
      "spatialReference":{"wkid":102100,"latestWkid":3857}
    }
  }]
}
```

Could there be something wrong with my request or is there a server/service option I've missed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the response syntax and example in the documentation [here](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcgis-rest-api/index.html#/Identify_Map_Service/02r300000113000000/), ArcGIS Server should definitely be returning the spatialReference to you explicitly.

see [this thread](https://geonet.esri.com/thread/112325) for more info about the confirmed bug.

Comment: Thanks! I'll just add that your link also contains a user suggested workaround, which is the same that solved my issue too.